# Why is there no icon for edit content in material design icons?

Tags: icons, material-design

I'm looking for a Material Design Icon for editing content. On https://www.google.com/design/icons/, there are icons designed for adding and deleting content, but nothing for editing content (which seems like a big omission to me). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Edit is usually denoted by the Pencil icon. Look in Content > Create. You'll also see it in Editor > Mode Edit and Image > Edit.